# java.util.Map / HashMap JAXB to JSON with Jackson - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to narrow content type

Tags: json, dictionary, jaxb, jackson

while trying to de-serialize class with Map/HashMap property from json message annotated with JAXB annotations I am getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to narrow content type [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class blog.map.generated.Address]] with content-type annotation (blog.map.generated.Customer$AddressMap): Class blog.map.generated.Customer$AddressMap is not assignable to blog.map.generated.Address
```

My json message:

```
{"addressMap":{"shipping":{"street":"2 B Road"},"billing":{"street":"1 A Street"}}}
```

My JAXB annotated class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customer", propOrder = {
"addressMap"
})
public class Customer {

@XmlElement(required = true, type = Customer.AddressMap.class)
protected HashMap<String, Address> addressMap;
public HashMap<String, Address> getAddressMap() {
    return addressMap;
}

public void setAddressMap(HashMap<String, Address> value) {
    this.addressMap = value;
}
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "entry"
})
public static class AddressMap {

    protected List<Customer.AddressMap.Entry> entry;

    public List<Customer.AddressMap.Entry> getEntry() {
        if (entry == null) {
            entry = new ArrayList<Customer.AddressMap.Entry>();
        }
        return this.entry;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "key",
        "value"
    })
    public static class Entry {

        protected java.lang.String key;
        protected blog.map.generated.Address value;

        public java.lang.String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(java.lang.String value) {
            this.key = value;
        }

        public blog.map.generated.Address getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(blog.map.generated.Address value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

}
}
```

I tried to avoid this problem by creating custom XmlAdapter for HashMap property as follows:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, Address>> {

public static class AdaptedMap {
    public List<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<Entry>();
}
public static class Entry {
    public String key;
    public Address value;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Address> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Address> map = new HashMap<String, Address>();
    for(Entry entry : adaptedMap.entry) {
        map.put(entry.key, entry.value);
    }
    return map;
}

@Override
public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, Address> map) throws Exception {
    AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Address> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        entry.key = mapEntry.getKey();
        entry.value = mapEntry.getValue();
        adaptedMap.entry.add(entry);
    }
    return adaptedMap;
}
}
```

That works BUT creates DIFFERENT MESSAGE than I need to deserialize:

```
{"addressMap":{"entry":[{"key":"shipping","value":{"street":"2 B Road"}},{"key":"billing","value":{"street":"1 A Street"}}]}}
```

Which is somewhat logical as it was converted to List of key-value pairs.

When I delete that "Map -> List of Key-Value pairs conversion" than IT WORKS!

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customer", propOrder = {
"addressMap"
 })
public class Customer {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected HashMap<String, Address> addressMap;


public HashMap<String, Address> getAddressMap() {
    return addressMap;
}

public void setAddressMap(HashMap<String, Address> value) {
    this.addressMap = value;
}

}
```

Does anybody know how to deal with such issue using Jackson 2.2.2 and JAXB? OR How to force XJC not to generate Map->List of KV pairs conversion?

Thanks